# nested loops on array object wrong result

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

This is my data structure:

```
array:2 [▼
  "1.5.8.5.2.44785" => array:2 [▼
    0 => {#300 ▶}
    1 => {#340 ▶}
  ]
  "1.5.8.5.2.22008" => array:3 [▼
    0 => {#405 ▶}
    1 => {#445 ▶}
    2 => {#487 ▶}
  ]
]
```

The inside row of the array contains some datas. nothing special!
Each task is unique to one workflow as well.

I need to print the external arrays key (that is the common id of the internal object). And then some content of each, internal obj of the array.

So i wrote in a blade view some php code as follow:

```
@if(is_array($workflows))
    @foreach(array_keys($workflows) as $workflowId)
        <p class="card-text">workflowid: {{$workflowId}}</p>
            @foreach($workflows as $tasks)
                    @foreach($tasks as $task)
                        idTask: {{$task->id}}</br>
                    @endforeach
            @endforeach
    @endforeach
@else
    <p class="card-text">No tasks</p>
@endif
```

If i print `dd($tasks)` the content is the one that im expect. -only tasks from the first cell of the external array, so only the right tasks for this current workflowId-

If i print `dd($task)` same thing, the content is just what im expect.... the current task!

The result is ok for the arrays_keys, that are printed right, then inside ive twice the same output, and the wrong one, all task are listed and not justs ones that is part of the current workflow, and I wonder why!!!!

```
workflowid: 1.5.8.5.2.44785

idTask: 1135102 (right task for this workflowid) 
idTask: 1135104 (right task for this workflowid) 
idTask: 1135185 (wrong task for this workflowid) 
idTask: 1135186 (wrong task for this workflowid) 
idTask: example (wrong task for this workflowid) 

workflowid: 1.5.8.5.2.22008

idTask: 1135102 (wrong task for this workflowid) 
idTask: 1135104 (wrong task for this workflowid) 
idTask: 1135185 (right task for this workflowid) 
idTask: 1135186 (right task for this workflowid) 
idTask: example (right task for this workflowid)
```

what im wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate with `foreach` using both key and value:

```
@if(is_array($workflows))
    @foreach($workflows as $workflowId => $tasks)
        <p class="card-text">workflowid: {{$workflowId}}</p>
            @foreach($tasks as $task)
                idTask: {{$task->id}}</br>
            @endforeach
    @endforeach
@else
    <p class="card-text">No tasks</p>
@endif
```

Comment: Because with `$workflows as $tasks` you iterate over all `$workflows` subarrays.